# convert Enumerable row collection <short> to short

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I have this error can't implicitly convert Enumerable row collection `<short>` to short in this line of code:

```
Month = (from item in query select (short)item.Month);
```

I want to know why and why I can't find distinct() or count method in query variable.

here is my method:

```
 public bool IsEnableAccPosting(
      string CompanyCode, DateTime FromDate, DateTime ToDate, out short Month)
 {
     try
     {
         o_dmDebitAccounts = new dmDebitAccounts(sysInfo);

         bool IsEnable = false;

         DataTable dt = o_dmDebitAccounts.GetDebitInterestAccPeriods(CompanyCode);

         var query = from data in dt.AsEnumerable()
                     where data.Field<DateTime>("StartDate") == FromDate && 
                           data.Field<DateTime>("EndDate") == ToDate
                     select new 
                     {
                         Month = Convert.ToInt16(data.Field<short>("Month")),
                         Year = Convert.ToInt16(data.Field<short>("Year"))
                     };

         Month = (from item in query select (short)item.Month); //heres the error
```

Answer (score 0):

The field is already typed as an Int16 in the linq query that is performing the operation. You dont need to cast it.

try the following code [taken from here](http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2008/04/24/checking-for-empty-enumerablerowcollections-when-using-linq.aspx)

```
if (query.Any())
{
    var result = query.First();

    // Console.WriteLine("Results: {0}", result.Month);
    Month = result.Month;

}
```

Comment: you mean:Month = (from item in query select item.Month);

Comment: i did so but also i didnt work and i want to know why i cant find FirstOrDefault();

Comment: No. In the code `Month =Convert.ToInt16( data.Field<short>("Month"))` is clearly casting the anonymous type's Month property as a Int16. Where is no reason to try casting it again, it is already that type.

Comment: var query = from data in dt.AsEnumerable()
                            where data.Field<DateTime>("StartDate") == FromDate && data.Field<DateTime>("EndDate") == ToDate
                            select new 
                            {
                                Month = data.Field<short>("Month"),
                                Year =data.Field<short>("Year")};

Comment: Why would removing the casting help you?!? You specifically wanted the value as an int16 in your question!? Sorry man, but I'm not sure what you are trying to do at this point.

Comment: i edited the code and remove the casting to int16 ,what i am trying to do that i want to set get from query value of Month.

Comment: First, dont remove the cast to int16. An Int16 is a short. Second, if you are trying to get a single value from an IQueryable you need to perform some type of scalar action on it. So `var monthVal = (from item in query select item.Month).FirstOrDefault(); Month = monthVal;` should be all you need.

Comment: i get this message system.data.enumrablerowcollection <short> doesnt contain defination for FirstOrDefaul()